# How to check if an element is not in the page anymore?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have defined a directive, which can be used on a button, and if the button is clicked, it will remote some elements from document, the code looks like:

```
.directive("mydirective", function() {
  return {
     link: function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
           $timeout(function() {
               angular.element("#aaa").remove();
           }, 1000);
        });
     }
});
```

Now I want to test it with protractor, the code looks like:

```
$("#mybutton").click();   // the button has the 'mydirective'

// wait until "#aaa" is removed
browser.wait(function() {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    $("#aaa").isPresent().then(function(data) {       // !!!!
        deferred.fulfill(!data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}, 2000);

// checking
expect($("#aaa").isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

But when I run the test, it will report:

```
Error: Locator cannot be empty
```

on the `!!!!` line in the code.

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1086?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use the [`ElementFinder`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder):

> The ElementFinder can be treated as a WebElement for most purposes, in
>   particular, you may perform actions (i.e. click, getText) on them as
>   you would a WebElement. ElementFinders extend Promise, and once an
>   action is performed on an ElementFinder, the latest result from the
>   chain can be accessed using then. Unlike a WebElement, an
>   ElementFinder will wait for angular to settle before performing finds
>   or actions.

```
element(by.id('mybutton')).click();
expect(element(by.id('aaa')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

UPD. Turned out that [`isElementPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.isElementPresent) eventually worked in this case:

```
expect(browser.isElementPresent(by.id('aaa'))).toBe(false);
```

Comment: I tried this code and it reports: `Expected true to be false.` I think that may because the `#aaa` is removed after 1000 ms, not immediately.

Comment: @Freewind okay, just for testing purposes, could you try `expect(browser.isElementPresent(by.id('aaa'))).toBe(false);`? Thanks.

Comment: @Freewind also, try setting the implicit wait timeout before running the spec: `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000);`.

Comment: `browser.isElementPresent` is working very well, and thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: @alecxe Why did you rollback to the `isPresent` version please?

Comment: @glepretre updated the answer, though I'm not completely sure why `isPresent` didn't work and `isElementPresent()` worked.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the promises.  They are implied.

```
browser.driver.wait ->
    browser.driver.isElementPresent(By.id 'aaa').then (present) -> !present
```